# Can't login using Webview Android

Tags: android, authentication, webview

The things is that I'm trying to access to the page of my university using a WebView on an Activity, but when I try to log in the app closes then the phone's web browser opens and it loads the page to log in again.

I don't understand, is this some security? is there a way to get through this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this code

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.ojoooview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://wad.ojooo.com/register.php?ref=legendbalaraja");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

It will load website in same webview

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks!
Can you give me a little explanation? I don't understand the last part.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this method or something else...
specify your question with coding
Put this in your onCreate()

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
setContentView(web view);
```

Then load the desired web page using this to display it in your activity:

```
// Simplest usage: note that an exception will NOT be thrown
// if there is an error loading this page (see below).
webview.loadUrl("http://slashdot.org/");

// OR, you can also load from an HTML string:
String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
// ... although note that there are restrictions on what this HTML can do.
// See the JavaDocs for loadData() and loadDataWithBaseURL() for more info.
```

try the above method if not implemented..
for more reference go to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: Yes, I'm using loadUrl, the login page loads normally, I write my user and pass but when press login button the app closes and the phone's web browser opens with the same login page. I can login there normally.

Comment: for that take reference from the below link..
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#HandlingNavigation

Comment: check content under handling page navigation heading

Comment: The Bala Raja solution worked perfectly, thank you for answers.